# how to solve this error, CSVFormat with double quote using apache commons?

Tags: java, runtime-error, java-11, apache-commons

I have an error that I am not able to solve, I use Apache Commons to read my CSV file, but there is a line that contains a string with double quotes and it is not delimiter, it is part of the string, I would like an alternative to get out of the error that the application is giving. Here is the code and the error.

```
Reader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(nomeArquivoCorretores),  Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));      
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat
                    .newFormat(',')
                    .withQuote('"')
                    .withEscape('\\')
                    .withHeader(cabecalhoCorretores)
                    .withTrailingDelimiter()
                    .withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.ALL)
                    .parse(in);
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
                try { ... }
```

I am getting this type of error when trying to go through the csv iterable list.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: IOException reading next record: java.io.IOException: (line 1) invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter.

it understands as if the double quotation mark is a delimiter, but it is part of the string and is breaking the algorithm process

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the example input? An the exact error message? (A [mcve] greatly increases your chances for an answer.) Just guessing: It sounds like you have a broken CSV file with fields that doen't have quotes escaped [properly](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180). If that's the case, check with whoever produces that file.

Comment: Robert I edited the question and I am still getting the error when executing the code.

Comment: What is the line of input that causes the error?

Comment: 86954708000105,"LOPES "G" ADMC.CORRETORA DE SEGUROS LTDA",PJ, ,0,Suspenso,,,,

Answer (score 1):

Your input CSV is invalid. In section 2, item 7, [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2) states:

> If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote.

This is not the case here:

> 86954708000105,"LOPES "G" ADMC.CORRETORA DE SEGUROS LTDA",PJ, ,0,Suspenso,,,,

which should be

> 86954708000105,"LOPES ""G"" ADMC.CORRETORA DE SEGUROS LTDA",PJ, ,0,Suspenso,,,,

Probably the best way to fix this is to **fix the program that produces this invalid CSV**.

If that is not possible, you can try to work around it, but it's gonna be a brittle hack. Assuming that the buggy CSV generator is at least consistent in how it's buggy and never doubles quotes within fields, you could first read the file as plain text, hackishly try to fix the quotes, and then feed the result to the actual CSV reader.

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.csv.*;

public class CsvHack {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String csvdata = "86954708000105,\"LOPES \"G\" ADMC.CORRETORA DE SEGUROS LTDA\",PJ, ,0,Suspenso,,,,";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(csvdata));

        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.replaceAll("([^,])\"", "$1\"\"");
            line = line.replaceAll("\",", "\"\",");
            buffer.append(line);
            buffer.append("\r\n");
        }
        Reader hack = new StringReader(buffer.toString());

        Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat
            .newFormat(',')
            .withQuote('"')
            .withEscape('\\')
            .withTrailingDelimiter()
            .withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.ALL)
            .parse(hack);
        for (CSVRecord record : records) {
            System.out.println(record.get(1));
        }
    }
}
```

This reads the whole file into a `StringBuilder` in memory (which may already be a no-go if you are dealing with large files), then it uses regular expressions to replace a quote that's not right after or right before a comma with two quotes. This will break if there are commas in the quoted text; regular expressions are the wrong tool for this.

An alternative would be to implement your own `java.io.Reader` and put that in between the file and the CSV parser, and in that reader's `read` method you fix the quotes.

If you get ever validly quoted CSV, these approaches will mess it up by adding extra quotes.

Again, I'd highly recommend to fix the program that outputs the defective CSV.